# WordPress: plugins don't load (only) on homepage after update

Tags: debugging, wordpress, plugins

After several plugins got updated yesterday I saw in the **source code** that actually **no plugin is loaded(1) on the frontpage anymore**. On all the other pages everything works just fine.

The most obvious one is the menubar (wp-menubar-plugin), and for now I made an exception for the homepage(2) loading a hard coded copy of the menu as I couldn't debug the issue.

For comparison:

- homepage: *as newby I only can post on link so please use the one below and click on "home" to compare the source code (only header) of the homepage and and all other pages. Sorry and Thank you ;)*
- other page example: http://www.ehpress.com/specials/

I tried some debugging by deactivating all plugins and activating one after the other with no change. I had a look through all my template files and couldn't find anything that could cause this 'exception'.

Has anyone experience with this or a similar behaviour?
I would be thankful for any hint where I could start with the debugging.

Thank you for any help,
Albert

(1) the easiest test is the 'All in One SEO Pack' which should be found in the header

(2) `if (is_page('home'))` ... echo css and in the body echo html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't exactly say what it was, but after the provider change some permissions so that I don't get the 550 error again all the plugins work again as well.

Thanks again for your help!

Albert